# Снова про вернуть, воротить.

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Правильно ли я понимаю, что корень "верт" из вертеть, родственный "ворот" из воротить, в слове вернуть обрезается в корень вер? И как часто такое происходит?

Answer (score 1):

Да,вертеть-воротить - чередование е/о,
от верт/е/ть + -НУ- - вертнуть, но 3 согласных подряд в русском языке не произносятся, Т исчезло, ( есть разговорное вертануть, сыграл закон сингармонизма - рядом с согласным гласный), получилось  вернуть.

```
как часто такое происходит?
```

Например,блеснуть,хотя блестеть, склянка ('стеклянный сосуд' ),хотя стекло, стеклянный, серчать,хотя сердиться, скатёрка,хотя скатерть.

Comment: Глядеть - глянуть, захолодеть - захолонуть.